# Can't launch firefox instance on screen 2 from terminal

Tags: pi-4, firefox

first post here!
Im having issues successfully launching firefox on my second 4k screen, anyone have any ideas? The second instance is running in the background on the first monitor, but is unable to move to the second screen.

This is the script im running:

```
# !/bin/bash

# Open Firefox on screen 1 (left screen) with the first URL in kiosk mode
DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox --kiosk "https://google.com" &

# Wait for Firefox process to start
sleep 5

# Open Firefox on screen 2 (right screen) with the second URL in kiosk mode and using profile "Default 1"
DISPLAY=:0.1 firefox --kiosk "https://google.com" &

# Wait for Firefox processes to start
sleep 5

# Move Firefox windows to the correct screens
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowmove --sync 0 0
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowmove --sync 3840 0

# Maximize Firefox windows
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate --sync key F11

# Leave the script running
wait
```

Comment: on which OS + version is this?

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit) 2023-12-05 release